# Strangely high number of upvotes to a self-answered question in a short period of time

Tags: discussion, voting, stack-exchange, up-votes

Strangely high number of upvotes to a self-answered question in a short period of time:

[How do I write a C header file that can be used in C++ programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548490/preprocessor-directive-to-test-if-this-is-c-or-c)

What's going on here?

Comment: Looks legit to me. If there was sockpuppeting going on, the question would likely have more than 1 upvote.

Comment: @Mystical unless that's how he *wants* you to think.

Comment: @Flavious - This is just a bikeshed question. The answer is upvoted by a lot of people thinking "I knew that, good answer". Now closed as a duplicate by those who also knew it had been asked before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Far as I can tell... someone posted a good question/answer pair. That's all. I'm not turning up any malicious activity on this one.

A single vote on a question and 6 upvotes/1 downvote (at the time of this writing; probably more now that the question has been linked on meta :)) on a good answer within 40 minutes of posting isn't *that* unusual, or at least one would hope it wouldn't be on a site as popular as Stack Overflow.